# Is it ok to put a ceramic lamp holder (for high brightness LED) in between joists in basement?

Tags: electrical, basement, light-fixture, lamp

In my small, unfinished, low basement are currently two fluorescent tubes as main lights. This is how it looks when I take a picture from the floor straight up to the ceiling of the basement:

[image]

I would like to replace the fluorescent tubes with lamp holders like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HJBCGU) and screw these flexible, very high brightness LED lamps in it (like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BXB8D3SV)).

However, I do not want to install the light fixture on the face of the joists because the basement is already so low. Instead I would like to screw them in between two joists, exactly where I marked the red cross in the picture. This saves valuable space and since these LED lamps are flexible and extend quite a bit out, that would still work without issues.

Is there any problem installing it like described?

Comment: The lamps themselves might be a problem in the US.  CE listing is not recognized.  As far as I know, only Japan uses 100v.  Not sure if they use 260w as what it uses for real or is the equivalent to an incandescent bulb.  I think if you do use them it would equal to using stadium lights in the basement.

Comment: ‘very high brightness’ is an understatement. Keep your receipt handy for the return!

Comment: Other than the comments already received, I'd recommend spacing the bulb holder down from the subfloor so that the entire bulb is below the joists, otherwise you're just wasting light trying to light up the sides of the joists.

Comment: Beware of screw length if attaching the junction box to the subfloor. You might find painful evidence upstairs if you use screws that are too long. Which is another reason to add some wood between the joists to attach the box to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lamp holder must be attached to a box like this [metal box](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Gray-Metal-New-Work-Old-Work-Standard-Octagonal-Ceiling-Wall-Electrical-Box/3129645?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-elc-_-ggl-_-LIA_ELC_206_Conduit-Fittings-Boxes-_-3129645-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjww7KmBhAyEiwA5-PUSvepywcn7CvJeNN0xq0MmgwE1rxTsw4pM81wPiyI3wJNNHiNWrxHhxoC4rIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), or one similar in plastic.  It cannot be mounted to the floor or joists by itself.

Your wiring must be done properly with strain relief and anchoring of the cable at least 8 inches from the box.  With that done properly you can safely use the ceramic lamp holders.

Then you can screw in your fixture and have better light. You may note that the light fixture you indicated does not show a UL rating.